# how can i get the even index object in a list useing swift 5?

Tags: swiftui, swift5

```
import SwiftUI

struct Videolist: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    static var videolist = ModelData().videolist
    @State private var j  = 0
    var total = Videolist.videolist.count
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Videolist.videolist.indices) { i in
                NavigationLink(destination: videoinfo(video: Videolist.videolist[i])) {
                    if i < 10 {
                        videoblock(video1: Videolist.videolist[i],video2: Videolist.videolist[i+1])
                    }
            }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("video")
        }
    }
}

struct videolist_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Videolist()
            .environmentObject(ModelData())
    }
}
```

I am trying to learn swift5 myself, anyBody can. explain to be why to code up work, but the code below does not work?

```
import SwiftUI

struct Videolist: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    static var videolist = ModelData().videolist
    @State private var j  = 0
    var total = Videolist.videolist.count
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(Videolist.videolist.indices) { i in
                NavigationLink(destination: videoinfo(video: Videolist.videolist[i])) {
                    if j < 10 {
                        videoblock(video1: Videolist.videolist[i],video2: Videolist.videolist[i+1])
                        j += 1
                    }
            }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("video")
        }
    }
}

struct videolist_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Videolist()
            .environmentObject(ModelData())
    }
}
```

I want to set two video cover in one line
by check if j is even, then set a NavigationLink,like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMwG3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are over complicating your `View` give this a try.

The `body` of a SwiftUI `View` only returns other `View`s. This line `j += 1` is not a `View` so it does not belong in a `body`.

As a general rule a SwiftUI `View` should never do any work it is just the for the UI the model should do all the work.

```
import SwiftUI
class ModelData: ObservableObject{
    @Published var videolist: [String] = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O"]
}
struct VideoListView: View {
    //This static instance of ModelData has no connection with the videolist on the next line of code
    @EnvironmentObject var modelData: ModelData
    //This instance of ModelData has no connection to the line above
    // Plus any changes will never be relayed
    //static var videolist = ModelData().videolist
    //Not needed, if you find yourself needing one of these in a SwiftUI View you need to rethink your approach
    //@State private var j  = 0
    
    
    //This instance gets the init value with the static variable but will never be updated to account for additions and subtractions becuase there isnt any observing
    //Get rid of videolist & total. Use the @EnvironmentObject var modelData directly
    //var total = Videolist.videolist.count
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView{
                //By setting the count to 2 you are saying you want 2 columns / 2 items per row
                LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)) {
                    //Using indices is not ideal practice use the object itself as much as possible
                    //Using the static variable will prevent updates
                    //Based on your code I assume you only want this behavior for the first 10 objects
                    ForEach(modelData.videolist.prefix(10), id:\.self) { video in
                        NavigationLink(destination: Text("videoinfo(video: video \(video)")) {
                            
                            Text("video \(video)")
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("video")
            }
        }
    }
}


struct VideoListView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VideoListView().environmentObject(ModelData())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, this is what I want, also fulfill my wander.

Comment: Awesome, if I answered your question will you accept the answer?